# Tableau...how to add SUM of AGG(Measure) from worksheet to dashboard

Tags: tableau

I am working in Tableau to build a dashboard that summarized various measures pertaining the the loss and gain of types of forests. The dashboard shows a bar chart of losses and gains: [Losses and Gains chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXHaW.png)

The chart was created from a calculation that finds the sum of acres for a year and subtracts the sum of acres from a previous year (there are also additional filters in place for agency, unit, and land type). The calculation used is:

```
(SUM([Thsnd Acres]))-(LOOKUP(SUM([Thsnd Acres]),-1))
```

When viewing the chart in the worksheet, at the bottom of the worksheet the SUM of AGG(LossGain): 47.8 is displayed like this: 
[Image of SUM of AGG(LossGain)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrB8l.png)

I am trying to figure out a way of adding that summed information to the dashboard. When I try to create additional SUM calculations, I am getting errors that indicate I cannot sum an existing aggregation. Because the information is displayed at the bottom of the worksheet, it has to be possible to get that number in a way that it can be inserted into a dashboard.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. It seems like this should be a fairly simple thing to do, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference line for that SUM shown at the bottom by right-clicking the vertical axis and selecting "Add reference line". Configure the Line Value as "LossGain" and "Sum". Adjust other settings as you prefer.

[image]